# NSOutlineview weird behaviour

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am sorry for the vague title, but I honestly don't know how to better put it. Currently I am trying to create a simple NSOutlineView. The idea is to have some cities sorted into their states. The following represents how the NSOutlineView should look[image: Correct Layout]

Now as you can see there can be a lot of children in one expandable item. The problem is that after opening and closing some states, there appear some blank lines and some cities get put in random locations or even disappear like the following image shows:[image: Incorrect Layout]

Obviously I have done some research on my own, and have found out some interesting points. 
This problem starts happening when the expanded state has a lot of cities in it and not all cities fit into the window. Seems to me like some children won't load correctly if they are not on screen.

I have seen similar questions where they recommended to disable `Floats Group Rows` which I did but nothing has changed.

To me this looks like an underlying issue with the NSOutlineView, but I could be wrong. I am happy to show any code upon request, I don't want to clutter the entire post with random code as I don't know what could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution for anyone in the future with similar issues. In the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview) they state:

> Important
>
> It is possible that your data source methods for populating the
>   outline view may be called before awakeFromNib() if the data source is
>   specified in Interface Builder. You should defend against this by
>   having the data source’s outlineView(_:numberOfChildrenOfItem:) method
>   return 0 for the number of items when the data source has not yet been
>   configured. In awakeFromNib(), when the data source is initialized you
>   should always call reloadData().

Therefore I called `reloadData()` in `awakeFromNib()` the problem however, was that `awakeFromNib()` was called multiple times whenever you expand an item, these multiple reloads caused an issue with displaying the elements, hence my solution was simply removing the `reloadData()` from `awakeFromNib()`